# LINQ to Entities GroupBy, OrderByDescending, FirstOrDefault when

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008, linq-to-entities

I have a following problem with LINQ to Entities. I am selecting records from  DB, group them and then order them by Id descending. Then i want to select First item but only if Quantity is != 0. I think because i have to use FirstOrDefault i am getting wrong results but am not sure how to correct it.

DB

[image]

Now this query will give me  ID's 2 and 1 grouped and 4 "grouped". What i need is to select FIRST items only if Quantity is != 0 and am not sure how to get that.

```
data = DbContext.Items.Where(x.WarehouseId == 1)
                .GroupBy(x => x.ItemCode, (key, g) => g.OrderByDescending(y => y.Id).FirstOrDefault())
                .OrderBy(parameters.SortExpression)
                .Skip(parameters.Start)
                .Take(parameters.Length);
```

If WarehouseID is 1 i need to get only row with ID 4 back. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: First i need to groupBy ItemCode, then i will have two groups for my case above. That's 1 and 2 for first group, and 4 for second group. Then i order them by Id descending and i get (2, 1), (4). Then i need to select first from group but only if Quantity is != 0. If Quantity is zero i don't want to select anything from a group.

Image to clarify what i need. I'm stuck on last step Take FristFrom each group only if quantity is != 0

[image]

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This is, what you want to do:

```
var data = DbContext.Items
            .Where(p => p.WarehouseId == 1)
            .GroupBy(p => p.ItemCode, (key, items) => new { Key = key, Items = items, ItemsCountWithQuantityZero = items.Where(p => p.Quantity == 0).Count() })
            .Where(p => p.ItemsCountWithQuantityZero == 0)
            .Select(p => p.Items.OrderByDescending(q => q.Id).First());
```

Comment: First i need to groupBy ItemCode, then i will have two groups for my case above. That's 1 and 2 for first group, and 4 for second group. Then i order them by Id descending and i get (2, 1), (4). Then i need to select first but only if Quantity is != 0. If Quantity is zero i don't want to select anything from a group.

Comment: In your second case you are getting only Ids 1 and 4 when you should get 2 and 4, see that 2 has Quantity 0 and ignore it so you are only left with 4 at the end.